# Creating legend of variable length datasets+ignoring empty cells

Tags: matlab, legend, is-empty, variable-length-array

I'm trying to plot some monthly statistics that span over 2 years, where 1 year has only one month of data and the other has 11 months of data. Where I'm having trouble is in the legend label, when I am filling out the label it takes the one month of data from the first year and puts behind the next years labels, as if it is filling in that month. Here's what I mean:

```
    legendms=['PIC2 -- HHN Jan 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Feb 13', PIC2 -- HHN March 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Apr 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN May 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN June 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN July 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Aug 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Sept 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Oct 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Nov 13', 'PIC2 -- HHN Dec 12']
```

Where 13 is the 2 digit representation for 2013, and 12 for 2012. It does this even though I am cycling through the years in order. I believe it is because legendms for year 2012 is essentially empty cells except for Dec, and so it's just filling in the space. It is also not following the appropriate line styles either. It labels Jan 13 a different line style '-' than the others when Dec 12 should be the different line style. Does anyone know a way around this, or how to ignore the empty cells while still retaining a full legend label?

Here's the code I have so far, perhaps I am just making a simple mistake? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
close all;
  for ms=1:length(stats)
    legendms=[];
     for i = 1:length(files)
       figure
        for y = 1:length(files(i,1).year)
     if (files(i,1).comp(1) == 'H')
       xvals = files(i,1).allData{7}(1:114);
     elseif (files(i,1).comp(1) == 'B')
       xvals = files(i,1).allData{7}(1:95);
     end
        for m = 1:length(files(i,1).year(y).month)
  %Set up generic month string
  if ~isempty(files(i,1).year(y).month(m).(x{ms}))
    monthString = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};
    %Set up month string particular to this dataset 
    mString= monthString(1:length(files(i,1).year(y).month));
    yString=cellstr(num2str(year));
    %Set up axis variable particular to this dataset
    axisVar = [1 length(mString) -70 10];
    LineColors={rgb('red') rgb('blue') rgb('green') rgb('indigo') rgb('cyan')   
    rgb('orange')  rgb('HotPink') rgb('DarkGray') rgb('purple') rgb('BurlyWood') 
    rgb('yellow') rgb('Salmon')};

    %Loop through stats to plot 
 semilogx(xvals,files(i,1).year(y).month(m).(x{ms}),LineStyles{y}, 'Color', LineColors{m},
 'LineWidth',lWidth)
 hold on

 %Set axis interval
 axis([0.1, 172, -190, -80]);

 %Set the axis label max, min, and interval for the Yaxis
  set(gca,'YTick', [-190:10:-80])

  %Label x and y axis and create cell for legend for each sta, loc, chan per
  %file to use below. Make title for each plot
  xlabel('Period (s)','FontSize',labelSize);
  ylabel('Power (dB)','FontSize',labelSize);
  legendms{m} = [legendms ' ' files(i,1).sta ' ' files(i,1).loc ' ' files(i,1).comp ' '  
  monthString{m} ' ' yString{y}(3:4)];

  title([x{ms} ' ' 'Monthly Comparisons', ' ' num2str(files(i,1).allData{2}(1)) '/' 
  num2str(files(i,1).allData{3}(1)) '/' num2str(files(i,1).allData{1}(1)) '-' 
  num2str(files(i,1).allData{2}(end)) '/' num2str(files(i,1).allData{3}(end)) '/' 
  num2str(files(i,1).allData{1}(end))],'FontSize',titleSize);

    end 
  end
end

   %Plot NLNM and NHNM models and label legend for each figure

    semilogx(nlnmx,nlnmy,'k-','LineWidth',lWidth)
    semilogx(nhnmx,nhnmy,'k-','LineWidth',lWidth)
    hold off
    legend([legendms, 'NLNM', 'NHNM'], 'Location', 'EastOutside')
    end
   end
```

To reiterate I would like the legend to ignore the empty cells for any of the years and plot the legend label in order from the years using the appropriate colors and station labels. 2012 values should be a solid line and 2013 values a dashed line, with whatever colors are representative of the month they describe (lineColors).

Comment: You're iterating through `files` and `files(i).year` in order - are they correctly sorted? Bear in mind if you're using `dir` you _must_ assume the list of files is unsorted since you get whatever order the system feels like giving you.

Comment: Yes, they are correctly sorted as they are separated within my structure so that files (i,1).year(1) is 2012 and files(i,1).year(2) is 2013. It loops through 2012 first and then 2013, but I think since the empty cells exist in 2012 it's filling in dec 2012 into the line style and color of a 2013 dec. Do you think maybe it's because of looping through m, that there are 12 months in each? Even though all of the twelve cells aren't filled ?

Comment: Do you know how to get around this behavior ?

Comment: Ah, assigning into `legendms{m}` is _probably_ part of it. I don't have time to look at it properly for a full answer, but what if you try just growing `legendms` in order, e.g. `legendms{end+1} = ...`? (obviously create an empty `legendms = {};` beforehand)

Comment: @Notlikethat this worked! Using the legendms{end+1}, but will this work in all scenarios or only when there's one month in a year and a full year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing legendms with the variable "m," which loops through all the files, even when they are empty.  However, you are only plotting using semilogx when the the file is not empty.

Either:

Create a new variable (initialize to 0) and increment it in the

```
if ~isempty
```

statement, and use that variable in legendms,

or

use legendms{end+1} as @notlikethat said to stretch it out, after initializing it to an empty cell.

PS:  if you use hold all instead of hold on, you do not need to define the line colors.

Comment: Lazarus, can you explain more by what you mean create a new variable if ~isempty. Do you mean I should have my isempty further up or define a new one? The trouble with putting it higher up is that in order to index the appropriate julian days for data that I actually have I have many empty days and month fields that have empty statistic calculations (x{ms}). The legendms{end+1} seems to work how I want it to. The hold all is a great tip and something I didn't know, but how do you get it to use different colors for each line? It seemed to loop over the same colors on my plot.

Comment: Leave the if statement in the same place.  Above the if statement, set count = 0, and after the if statement, set count = count+1.  Then use legendms{count}.  However, legendms{end+1} is also correct.  Yes, the hold all will loop over the same colors - I didn't notice you had defined 12 colors (one for each month I assume).

Comment: One thing is though the legendms{end+1} seems to retain all of the old legend values, I need it to remove them as it moves through the files. It doesn't seem to clear it...

Comment: Clear legendms with "legendms = {}" before the if statement.  The best place is probably right after or before you call the figure command.

Comment: Yep, you're correct! I had just figured out it needed to be in the i loop where I'm looping through the individual files. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like each legend entry is the accumulation of all the previous entries, which does not seem correct to me.  I think I would replace this line of code:

```
legendms{m} = [legendms ' ' files(i,1).sta ' ' files(i,1).loc ' ' files(i,1).comp ' '
```

monthString{m} ' ' yString{y}(3:4)];

with this line of code:

```
legendms{m} = [' ' files(i,1).sta ' ' files(i,1).loc ' ' files(i,1).comp ' '
```

monthString{m} ' ' yString{y}(3:4)];

Since you are missing some data, you will want to remove the blank entries from the legend cell array before calling legend.  I suggest adding code like this to remove the empty cell array elements.

```
is_empty = cellfun(@isempty, legendms);
legendms = legendms(~is_empty);
```

Comment: Thanks user3194690! I tried this one, as this was sort of along the lines of what I had been thinking and testing. It seems to create an increasing amount of cells as you move through the month but doesn't give exactly what I wanted. Perhaps I'm putting the cellfun component in the wrong loop-where would it go?